# Add field to PDF template

Tags: files

Hello I am working with [Views PDF](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_pdf) Module, and I am asking how could add a fields to the PDF template file

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

From the module page:

> With this module you can output a view as a PDF document. Each field
>   of the view can be placed on the PDF page directly in the
>   administration interface. Therefore a new display called "PDF" is
>   added.

So from within Views, add a PDF page display. Then add the fields you like.

[image: configuration]

Comment: Thanks for your answer ,I would like to ask how to position fields I had many issues on that

Comment: Can you update the question with what you have tried so far, and what did and did not work?